# What does 'Switch to Frame' do in the Visual Studio Call Stack Window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'd expect this to 'unwind' the call stack and return to a calling method (which is what Eclipse does). However, the MSDN documentation says

> A green arrow with a curly tail appears next to the frame you
>   selected. The execution pointer remains in the original frame, which
>   is still marked with the yellow arrow. If you select Step or Continue
>   from the Debug menu, execution will continue in the original frame,
>   not the frame you selected.

A green arrow with a curly tail? Nice. What else does it actually do? And is it possible to rewind the call stack?

Comment: It's just for viewing the variables etc on the stack for a particular method.

Comment: [Call stack time machine in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380260/call-stack-time-machine-in-visual-studio-2010)?